# UI Dialog moving outside of <form> tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, dialog

I have a form which contains multiple fields.

It also contains some fields which pop opens in Ui Dialog Box, when i fill those fields and close dialog box, the dialog take my fields and put it outside of the form right before `</body>` tag.

Look at this :

[image]

How can I keep it in form tag ? Because I need those fields in my form for posting.

I have some dynamically generated fields in this popup like **add more fields**.

Now if check this fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/xpkFf/258/

And check in firebug after opening and closing the popup, the form tag will appear empty.

Any solution please ?

I am posting data on another page using $_POST using php

Here is the example code :

**HTML:**

```
<form>
    <div id="dialog">
    <input type="text" name="first_name">
   </div>
 </form>
<a href="#" id="open">Open dialog</a>
```

**JS:**

```
$('#open').click(function() {
    $('#dialog').dialog('open');

});



$('#dialog').dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    modal: false
});
```

Comment: Move the form tag inside of dialog `<div id="dialog">
    <form>
        <input type="text" name="first_name" />
    </form>
</div>`

Comment: I dont want to put all of my data in dialog

Comment: What exactly you are trying to do? Dialog contains another form ?

Comment: Its very simple. I have a form, which contains fields, and dialog popup in it. that popup also contains some fields, everything in single form

Answer (score 0):

How are you sending that form data to the server?  If you are just using a $.post, you can .serialize() the form data and then just get the values of the items in the dialog and add them to it:

```
$.post('submitit.php', {  $("#myform").serialize() + "&anotherItem=" + $("#dialogItem").val () }, function (results) {
    // do something with results
}, "json");
```

Comment: I am posting data on another page using $_POST in php